# UseShellExecute unable to find file

Tags: c#, .net, console

```
    public void BuildMod()
    {
        var startIngo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startIngo.WorkingDirectory = ModBuilderLoc;
        startIngo.FileName = "ModPack Builder.exe";
        startIngo.Arguments = "\"" + 
                 LoadedMod.Directory.Substring(Folders.MyDocuments.Length + 28)
                 + "\"" + " " + "true";
        startIngo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal; //TODO: Set to hidden
        //startIngo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //startIngo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        try
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = startIngo;
            proc.Start();
            //proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("Build successful", "Build Info"); 
        }
        catch (Win32Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find \"ModPack Builder.exe\" in \"" 
                         + ModBuilderLoc +"\", change from menu bar");
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly fine, unless I uncomment the comments, which makes the program read the first line to my program's console.

When the comments are uncommented, a Win32 exception is caught, which I **do not** want happening.

Comment: perhaps adding the exception to the question would be helpful?

Comment: When UseShellExecute is false, the FileName property must be a fully qualified path to the executable. Try putting the full path to ModPack Builder.exe